# How to fill a custom typed List<> from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, class, user-defined

I have a class named `Author.cs` defined as:

```
public class Author : Interfaces.INode
{
    private List<INode> _targetList;
    private List<IAttribute> _attributeObject;

    // Author class Constructor
    public Author()
    {
        _targetList = new List<INode>();
    }
    //implementazion of _TargetObject INode method
    public List<INode> _TargetObject
    {
        get
        {
             return _targetList;
        }
    }
    //implementazion of _AttributeObject INode method
    public List<IAttribute> _AttributeObject
    {
        get
        {
             return _attributeObject;
        }
    }

    public int _aID { get; set; }
    public string _aName { get; set; }  
    // 'CoAuthor', 'Venue' and 'Paper' are classes that  
    // implements an interface i.e. `IAttribute`
    public List<CoAuthor> _aCoAuthors { get; set; } 
    public List<Venue> _aVenue { get; set; }
    public List<Paper> _aPapers { get; set; }
    public string _aArea { get; set; }
}
```

which implements an interface in `Interfaces` folder named `Interfaces.INode.cs` defined as:

```
public interface INode
{
    List<INode> _TargetObject { get; }
    List<IAttribute> _AttributeObject { get; }
}

public interface IAttribute : INode
{}
```

Now I want to fill a list i.e. `List<Author>` i.e. is in another class named `AuthorCollector.cs`

```
List<Author> _eAthors = new List<Author>();
```

I have tried as:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand _myCommand_1 = _con.CreateCommand();
    _myCommand_1.CommandText = @"SELECT Author_ID FROM M_DataFull  
                                 ORDER BY Author_ID, Year";
    var _AuthID = 0;
    int _Row_Counter = 0;

    using (SqlDataReader _myReader_1 = _myCommand_1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (_myReader_1.Read())
        {
            _Row_Counter++;
            _eAthors.Add(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"]));
        }
        _myReader_1.Close();
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

The error is:

> The best overloaded method match for `_eAuthors.Add()` has some invalid arguments.

Comment: you try to add an int to a list of authors. pseudo code: new Author(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"]));

Comment: @Mat same I asked how to fill that 'List<Author>' i.e. a custom typed list

Comment: Try to use Entity Framework it is more flexible

Comment: You have a List<Author> but you are adding an integer _eAthors.Add(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"])).  You first need to create a new author : Author newAuthor = new Author();.  Then add author to list : _eAthors.Add(newAuthor);.  Then set the author id : newAuthor._aID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader_1["Author_ID"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (SqlDataReader _myReader_1 = _myCommand_1.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (_myReader_1.Read())
    {
       _Row_Counter++;
       Author author = new Author();
       author._aId = Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"]);
       author._aName = Convert.ToString(_myReader_1["Author_Name"]);
       //etc...
       _eAthors.Add(author);
    }
    _myReader_1.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Nino--you have elegantly added a single author to the list, so what for more authors to add ?

Comment: code is inside while loop... so each author is added to list. It works for zero, one or more authors.

Comment: @Nino--what for other attributes of class `Author` as they are also itself custom typed lists as public `List<CoAuthor>`, `List<Venue>`, `List<Paper>` how to fill these ?

Comment: you'll have to fill them manually, like author. You can either change your query to join author to other tables or fill properties one by one using multiple database queries.

Comment: Can I use EF here ? As I have all of my data in SQL Server tables

Comment: of course you can, you should use EF. That will simplify a lot of things.

Comment: @Nino--please provide a quick review tutorial of EF, I have search but found all guidance relevant to code first regarding EF whereas I have filled up data in my SQL Server database

Comment: @Nino--that How to start with EF as all of your data resides already in the SQL Server database? Do you still need to create tables and fill them up using code first EF ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111436/discussion-between-nino-and-maliks).

Answer (score 0):

you try to add an int to a list of authors. pseudo code:

```
_eAthors.Add(new Author(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"])));
```

or

```
    _eAthors.Add(new Author(){_aID =Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"]}));
```

anyway I would use a ORM framework for this like NHibernate or EntityFramework. It's much easier than to do all the SQL Mapping yourself...

Comment: @Mat--still this is not the solution because we don't have any constructor in Author class that takes 1 argument

Comment: I've added a valid piece of code so you don't have to write a constructor :-)

Comment: @Mat--you are suggesting EntityFramework but I'm not very much familiar with this yet

Comment: That's why I made the suggestion.... a ORM can do this job for you so you don't have to code the materialization of objects from database

Answer (score 0):

`_eAthors` is a collection of `Authors`, but the code is trying to add an `int` value which is causing an error in this case.

Modify this line

```
_eAthors.Add(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"]))
```

to

```
_eAthors.Add(new Author
             {
                _aid= Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_1["Author_ID"]),  
                // add additional properties if you have one.                     
             });
```